# Scrapy error: TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'cb_kwargs'

Tags: scrapy

I use scrapy to parse the site. Scrapy version 2.1.0
when I try to make an additional request:

```
taglines_request = Request(url=tagline_url, 
                           callback=self.get_tags_and_awards,
                           cb_kwargs={'item':item, 'awards_url': awards_url})
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'cb_kwargs'
```

But in the __init __ () method, there is a cb_kwargs parameter. Tell me, please, what could be the problem?
I launch through ScrapyD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem here is that you are passing cb_kwargs to Request which Request in turn doesn't accept. From what I understand, cb_kwargs is new in Scrapy version 1.7, so you should check again if ScrapyD in your case is working with a version of Scrapy >= 1.7.
Alternatively, to pass data to your callback, you could use [Request's meta attribute](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html?highlight=meta#scrapy.http.Request.meta).

```py
taglines_request = Request(
    url=tagline_url, 
    callback=self.get_tags_and_awards,
    meta={
        'item':item, 
        'awards_url': awards_url
    }
)
```

You can then access the data from your response via meta.

```py
def get_tags_and_awards(self, response):
    item = response.meta['item']
    awards_url = response.meta['awards_url']
```